# XCode6 6.1.1. constraint issue on resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints, xcode6.1

I have a nib file with a layout including a `UIImage` and a few `UILabel`s. There are a few constraints on the existing UI elements. I added a new `UILabel` by dragging it onto the Interface. All is fine, but as soon as I try to resize the `UILabel` (has no constraints yet) the constraints of my already existing elements are reset by a few points. This happens every time I try to resize any new element. Any ideas? Could this be because of it being a `.xib` rather than `Storyboard` which is probably more up to date?

Comment: Perhaps there are no constraints for the existing elements, make sure they have some constraints before you resize the UILabel.

Comment: There are constraints, re-read my question.

Comment: I have read your question again and again, and I found out that if the existing elements have width and height constraints, they would stay the same size when you resize your label.

Comment: I have a feeling this is probably some bug as it moved all elements say by 1pt down. I see no relation between the dragged element and the existing ones. Thanks for checking though

Comment: It perhaps that some elements has a width value that is not integer such as 140.5, and sometimes the same happens to me when I reopen a project, but it is easy to fix, clicking the suggested frame changes and warning disappears.

Comment: Yes that is what I do. But it is a pretty annoying thing. Thanks for your help @gabbler